# How to make glass reflect illuminated objects but glass itself doesn't reflect light source?

Tags: light, glass

I want to make heat distortion effect in Cycles, but it reflects light source. If move effect on another Render layer & exclude light, then it reflects objects behind without light. How to make that this material not reflect light source, but to reflect objects behind with light on them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going into ray visibility and fiddling with the settings[image: showing the ray visibility settings]

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped to uncheck Transmission.